# iOS: Is there a better method to transmit Data to Server as POST?

Tags: ios, xcode, string, url, post

I have a URL String with a length of 1500 characters. Someone told me that such "huge" strings can not be transmitted correctly to the server.. (too long).

Is there a better method as POST? Or should I split the whole String?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tutorials for using HTTP POST and GET on the iPhone in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346893/tutorials-for-using-http-post-and-get-on-the-iphone-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem to send 1500 characters via HTTP POST.

Comment: What about 2500? (when I expand some day?)

Comment: Thats still just a few kByte, no problem there. People upload pictures with tens of MByte using HTTP POST and dont run into problems (considering your server to be able to handle the load).

Comment: Chris, I thought a URL could not be longer than 2000 characters (browser limit). Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: With HTTP POST you do not use the URL to send the data but the body of the request. Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP) for more info. I think you are confusing GET and POST!?

Comment: Right. But what is this long string for? one=..&two=..&...? THIS is a bit confusing..

Comment: Thats a HTTP GET Request: www.example.com?val1=one&val2=4