# how to call url with parameters in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

i have one php file for push notification service and working.. i want use that php file in xcode, for example send device token and message like an query string..

i used this code

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://xxxxxx.com/send-notification.php?token=%@&message=test";                       
NSString *escapedString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *add = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",escapedString,token]];`
```

but not working i don't know how to call this php..

thanks for all helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create your url in a different way. In your code, the `%@` in the initial `urlString` will not be replaced later on.

Instead, try writing your code like this:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xxxxxx.com/send-notification.php?token=%@&message=test", token];
NSString *escapedString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *add = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedString];
```

After you've created the NSUrl instance, you will have to open a http connection to the url.

Comment: hello can you send me how to open http connection ? thanks :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346893/tutorials-for-using-http-post-and-get-on-the-iphone-in-objective-c contains some good examples