# sending data using CURL in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

how i have to use the following CURL command in objective c,

curl -d lang=fr -d badge=0 http://www.redis.com/subscriber/J8lHY4X1XkU

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346893/tutorials-for-using-http-post-and-get-on-the-iphone-in-objective-c

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.redis.com/subscriber/J8lHY4X1XkU"];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSString* str = @"lang=fr&badge=0";
NSData* body = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setHTTPBody:body];
[req setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [str length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
```

More about this you can find on iOS documentation: [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSMutableURLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try following code?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.redis.com/subscriber/J8lHY4X1XkU?lang=fr&badge=0"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:120];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
NSData *responce = [NSURLConnection  sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:NULL error:NULL];
```