# Google Spreadsheet Protocol "A cell's position cannot be updated."

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, oauth-2.0, google-sheets-api

I currently have an XML file that needs to be sent to Google to update a cell in my worksheet/spreadsheet. I have written the XML with a library and I hope it's in the correct format as [Google's Spreadsheet API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#changing_contents_of_a_cell) asks.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346893/tutorials-for-using-http-post-and-get-on-the-iphone-in-objective-c) tutorial, I got as far as receiving a message that say's "A cell's position cannot be updated." I'm not sure what part I have done wrong but here's how I implemented the call to the API in Objective-C:

```
-(void) callAPI:(NSString *)apiURL withHttpMethod:(HTTPMethod)method XMLString:(NSString *) xml
{

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?access_token=%@", apiURL, _accessTokenInfoDictionary[@"access_token"]];
NSLog(@"URLString: %@", urlString);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]
                                initWithURL:[NSURL
                                             URLWithString:urlString]];
if (method == PUT) {

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];

    [request setValue:@"application/atom+xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[xml length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];

    [request setHTTPBody:[xml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [self makeRequest:request];
    }

}
```

I am using OAuth 2 with the help of [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/accessing-google-services-using-the-oauth-2-0-protocol/) but it doesn't handle xml files, therefore I have to implement a method for one.

The XML file that the app writes looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gs="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006">
<id>https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/theworksheetid/od6/private/full/R3C1</id>
<link rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/theworksheetid/od6/private/full/R3C1/15d60i" />
<gs:cell row="2" col="4" inputValue="Testing with XML Writer!!" />
</entry>
```

The access token that the method `callAPI` generates looks like this:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/theworksheetid/od6/private/full/R3C1/15d60i?access_token=some_access_token
```

So, I'm not sure if it's the way I implemented the method or if it's the XML file or the access token that doens't allow me to update the cell, but any help would do, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. The issue was that the row and the column from the created XML file didn't match with the row and column from that cell entry that was given to me. So all I had to do was match them, send the XML and tada, now I am able to edit cells!