# Using a Javascript API for iOS development

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

So basically I'm trying to learn more about iOS development and APIs, so I'm building an iOS app that allows people to search a zipcode and then it will return all of the restaurants currently open within a certain radius. I got the Google Maps API setup properly, but I'm running into issues with how to get that info.

I looked at the Google Places API and it looks like I will be able to get a JSON result and then I can just look for the "open_now" : true key/value. Currently, there is a Google Places API for Android and Javascript, but the iOS one is still in beta. Can I use this Javascript API to pass the JSON into my Obj-C code for iOS Development? Thanks!

Comment: Wait, are you looking for Objective-C or javascript? That's confusing. Perhaps this is what you are looking for: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

Answer (score 1):

To use the Google Places API make a simple POST request with [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

For example:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"key": @"YOUR_KEY", @"location": @"YOUR_LOCATION"};
[manager POST:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id   responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Now with the json "responseObject" you can do anything

Try to parse it with [json-framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework)

Comment: Wow, so this is all I need to get the json object? Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for info on how to parse JSON with Objective-C:
[How do I parse JSON with Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547311/how-do-i-parse-json-with-objective-c)

In a nutshell, use the `NSJSONSerialization` class to convert JSON to Foundation objects and Foundation objects to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the javascript API for that task. The Google Places API belongs to the Google Maps Web service suite, so you just need to make a http request in order to retreive the data.

Making http requests on obj-c is addressed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346893/tutorials-for-using-http-post-and-get-on-the-iphone-in-objective-c) and you'll just need to parse the JSON response.