# How do i get JSON data from a couchDB database and parse it in Xcode?

Tags: json, xcode, couchdb

For Example,
I have a document in my CouchDB database that holds two fields
"password" and "username".
This is the URL for my document:http://127.0.0.1:5984/_utils/document.html?sgram/fdcfc14940fbaa0d86674046ce005107
I want to retrieve the value of these fields from that specific document in CouchDB and parse it in Xcode.
I tried using http-get but it just returns the entire page source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make a request to this endpoint

http://127.0.0.1:5984/sgram/fdcfc14940fbaa0d86674046ce005107

For a json response from couchdb just don't include `_utils/document.html` in between.  If you do it will give you back the futon html page.

Comment: I also have another question regarding this topic,is it possible to use http-post in Xcode to modify the document too?If so,how?

Comment: I am not familiar with xcode but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346893/tutorials-for-using-http-post-and-get-on-the-iphone-in-objective-c) seems to have a good overview on making http get and post requests with it. If you are new to this try making post request with a simpler library like curl first to see if what you want to do works and then translate it into Xcode